# Ansible - Combine two dictionaries, but with a loop over the one

Tags: loops, dictionary

I have a static dictionary which I need to combine (to add it) to dynamic dictionary.

```
   "static": [
        {
            "item1": "abc",
            "item2": "def",
            "item3": "dkslks",
            "item4": "kkk"
        }
    ]


    "dynamic": [
        {
            "item5": "aa",
            "item6": "aaa",
            "item7: "aaaa"
        },
        {
            "item5": "bb",
            "item6": "bbb",
            "item7: "bbbb"
        },
        {
            "item5": "cc",
            "item6": "ccc",
            "item7: "cccc"
        }
    ]
```

I need to get the following result:

```
    "combined": [
        {
            "item1": "abc",
            "item2": "def",
            "item3": "dkslks",
            "item4": "kkk"
            "item5": "aa",
            "item6": "aaa",
            "item7: "aaaa"
        },
        {
            "item1": "abc",
            "item2": "def",
            "item3": "dkslks",
            "item4": "kkk"
            "item5": "bb",
            "item6": "bbb",
            "item7: "bbbb"
        },
        {
            "item1": "abc",
            "item2": "def",
            "item3": "dkslks",
            "item4": "kkk"
            "item5": "cc",
            "item6": "ccc",
            "item7: "cccc"
        }
    ]
```

I managed to combine it but just for the first part of this dict, not for all the members. Result was like this:

```
  - set_fact:
      combined: "{{ static|combine(dynamic) }}"


    "combined": [
        {
            "item1": "abc",
            "item2": "def",
            "item3": "dkslks",
            "item4": "kkk"
            "item5": "aa",
            "item6": "aaa",
            "item7: "aaaa"
        }
    ]
```

So I need to put it in a loop, but cannot find the right way. Here is some things I tried:

```
 - set_fact:
         combined: "{{ static | combine(json_query('[*]') | dynamic) }}"
```

or similar variations like this one

```
 - set_fact:
     combined: "{{ static | combine(dynamic) | json_query('[*]') }}"
```

or

```
  - set_fact:
      combined: "{{ dynamic | combine(static) }}"
    loop: "{{dynamic | json_query('[*]')}}"
```

Would someone be kind to help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A problem with several of your attempts is that both `dynamic` and `static` are lists, so they can't be used with the `combine` filter.

This seems to work with your sample data:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars_files:
    - data.yaml
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        combined: "{{ combined + [item|combine(static[0])] }}"
      vars:
        combined: []
      loop: "{{ dynamic }}"

    - debug:
        var: combined
```

This outputs:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'item5': 'aa', 'item6': 'aaa', 'item7': 'aaaa'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'item5': 'bb', 'item6': 'bbb', 'item7': 'bbbb'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'item5': 'cc', 'item6': 'ccc', 'item7': 'cccc'})

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "combined": [
        {
            "item1": "abc",
            "item2": "def",
            "item3": "dkslks",
            "item4": "kkk",
            "item5": "aa",
            "item6": "aaa",
            "item7": "aaaa"
        },
        {
            "item1": "abc",
            "item2": "def",
            "item3": "dkslks",
            "item4": "kkk",
            "item5": "bb",
            "item6": "bbb",
            "item7": "bbbb"
        },
        {
            "item1": "abc",
            "item2": "def",
            "item3": "dkslks",
            "item4": "kkk",
            "item5": "cc",
            "item6": "ccc",
            "item7": "cccc"
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```